What is a minimal requirements for a Frontier Template based blockchain's network?
I'm trying to figure out what a minimal blockchain would look like using substrate's frontier node.
What I'm trying to build:

A public minimal blockchain network
Aura consensus model
EVM and Ethereum RPC pallet included (like in frontier node)

What would a minimal production setup look like?
My assumption is that I will need at least 1 full node and 2 validator nodes but I'm not 100% sure.
I also have the following questions:

Can I replace the full node with an archive node in the minimal setup?
Do I need 2 validator nodes or can it work with just 1? (I believe the aura consensus model requires at least 2 validators)

It would be great if someone that has already done a production deployment of a solo chain using substrate could reply, or someone could point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

In addition to the above questions, upon some research I have a few more to add to the list:

On polkadot.js it says all the nodes in the network are either Validator nodes or Full nodes. Does this mean there are no Archive nodes, RPC nodes, Collator nodes in the network or do they expose them selves in conjunction with other nodes as a single (either Validator or Full) nodes and in reality is multiple nodes behind a proxy?
If the above assumption is correct, how do I set this up?

